# In R Markdown, why is a generate path not working, but the static result does?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I try to create an HTML report with R Markdown. I need a logo on the title page.
I was hoping to get a code as independent as possible, so no hardcoding of some path, but somehow it doesn’t work !

Here is what I try to do:

```
htmltools::img(src = knitr::image_uri(file.path(getwd(), "bin", "logo.png")), 
               alt = 'logo', 
               style = 'position:absolute; top:0; right:0; padding:10px;')
```

That is the error I get:

```
Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... paste0 -> base64_encode -> read_bin -> readBin -> file
Execution halted
```

However if run the command in the console and reuse the result directly it works !

```
> file.path(getwd(), "bin", "logo.png")
[1] "/Users/ber/Dropbox/Projet/R/eAPG/bin/logo.png"
```

```
htmltools::img(src = knitr::image_uri("/Users/ber/Dropbox/Projet/R/eAPG/bin/logo.png"), 
               alt = 'logo', 
               style = 'position:absolute; top:0; right:0; padding:10px;')
```

I don’t understand why it’s not working the way I hope. Can somebody help me ?

Cheers,
E

Comment: Is the Rmd you're knitting in this folder: `Users/ber/Dropbox/Projet/R/eAPG/` ?

Comment: @Edo No, it's in Users/ber/Dropbox/Projet/R/eAPG/src !
I try to use a clean directory structure for my R projects (./src, ./data, ./results, ./bin, ./doc).

Comment: Then I think that could be your problem. When knitting your working directory is the one where the Rmd is and that's where R looks for that file and obviously it doesn't find it.

Comment: @Edo Strange, because with the hardcoded result it's working:
`htmltools::img(src = knitr::image_uri("/Users/ber/Dropbox/Projet/R/eAPG/bin/logo.png"),`

Comment: No it's not strange. With the hardcoded  version you're telling R exactly where to look into. With the `getwd` function, R looks first for your working directory which is `Users/ber/Dropbox/Projet/R/eAPG/src`, from there it will look for the folder `bin` and the file `logo.png` and it won't find it because there is no file `Users/ber/Dropbox/Projet/R/eAPG/src/bin/logo.png`

Comment: @Edo You're right !!!!! :-D Thank you very much !!!! Following your explanation I tried: `htmltools::img(src = knitr::image_uri(file.path(getwd(), "..", "bin", "logo.png")),`and it worked perfectly ! Now I understand what happened and I can improve ! :-D